# How to test cross-contract Ink! contracts

Tags: ink, testing, cross-contract-call

In the latest master of Ink! examples there is only one main contract, `delegator`, for understanding cross-contract calls. Unfortunately, there are no tests either for this system.

- https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/927251c0d70ba9ac646add00acca082f8434b96a/examples/delegator/lib.rs

Cross-contract calling seems to rest on the `ContractRef` pattern where the `ContractRef`s are instantiated in the base contract's constructor.

```
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Delegator {
        /// Says which of `adder` or `subber` is currently in use.
        which: Which,
        /// The `accumulator` smart contract.
        accumulator: AccumulatorRef,
        /// The `adder` smart contract.
        adder: AdderRef,
        /// The `subber` smart contract.
        subber: SubberRef,
    }

    ...

    impl Delegator {
        /// Instantiate a `delegator` contract with the given sub-contract codes.
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(
            init_value: i32,
            version: u32,
            accumulator_code_hash: Hash,
            adder_code_hash: Hash,
            subber_code_hash: Hash,
        ) -> Self {
            let total_balance = Self::env().balance();
            let salt = version.to_le_bytes();
            let accumulator = AccumulatorRef::new(init_value)
                .endowment(total_balance / 4)
                .code_hash(accumulator_code_hash)
                .salt_bytes(salt)
                .instantiate()
                .unwrap_or_else(|error| {
                    panic!(
                        "failed at instantiating the Accumulator contract: {:?}",
                        error
                    )
                });
            let adder = AdderRef::new(accumulator.clone())
                .endowment(total_balance / 4)
                .code_hash(adder_code_hash)
                .salt_bytes(salt)
                .instantiate()
                .unwrap_or_else(|error| {
                    panic!("failed at instantiating the Adder contract: {:?}", error)
                });
            let subber = SubberRef::new(accumulator.clone())
                .endowment(total_balance / 4)
                .code_hash(subber_code_hash)
                .salt_bytes(salt)
                .instantiate()
                .unwrap_or_else(|error| {
                    panic!("failed at instantiating the Subber contract: {:?}", error)
                });
            Self {
                which: Which::Adder,
                accumulator,
                adder,
                subber,
            }
        }
    ...
    }
```

For testing, how does one create code hashes to instantiate the main contract that will delegate calls downstream?

Answer (score 9):

I'm posting a link to the discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1125.

AFAIK there is currently only the the possibility to do this with the redspot tool mentioned in the issue. I haven't tried it out myself though. Would be great if you could post in the issue if you managed to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in this [link](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1358) , Phala-Network is working on test cross-contract Ink! contracts and they have implemented cross-contract test in ink/examples/delegator/adder/ example