# Delegator-based contract causes UI interface to crash

Tags: ink, rust, ui

I have a funny problem, hopefully, someone can help.

I have an environment similar to the [delegator example contract](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator): one delegator-like contract, one accumulator-like contract, and one adder-like contract. I'm running a local test node. I can't deploy my contracts on the [contracts UI interface](https://%20https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/).

I can't compile the delegator contract because I get "ERROR: No 'ink_lang' dependency found". So I changed my dependencies on my contracts such that they look like this: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/5b0d36f56dfc3d83c55ca857f38e8d85

Code compiles for my three contracts. When deploying the adder-like and accumulator-like (in this order). However, when invoking the method from the accumulator contract that calls the adder contract, I obtain:

```
calling "delegator-add"
panicked at 'encountered error while calling Adder::add: NotCallable',
```

Why wouldn't it be callable? Of course, the delegator contract also does not work (and in fact breaks the interface)
I thought that the first problem could be a code problem, but i follow the tutorial very closely and it compiles. So I thought the dependencies might be the problem.

How can i change the dependency ink = { path = "../../crates/ink", default-features = false } to a non-local reference, such that I can have it instead of lines 8-13 of the gist I shared?

Unfortunately, [this similar question does not answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-to-test-cross-contract-ink-contracts) my question because I can't run the original delegator code nor use my version (fails on the mentioned occasion, but can call any function that is not doing a cross-contract call). I'm also not trying to explore the usage of  `ink_env::call::Call::new()`, but rather instantiate a delegator contract with references to deployed contracts so that I can call them directly.

Bonus points if you can point me to other smart contracts using the delegator design pattern.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to our recently published [delegator example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/delegator) which depends on the latest official ink! release.
Make sure you also use latest [cargo-contract](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-contract/2.0.2) version and [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases/tag/v0.24.0)