# ink! cross-contract calling tutorial does not compile

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call

Note: Having installed substrate-contracts-node and Contracts UI I can easily deploy and interact with an ink! Smart contract

I am following the ink! Tutorial here https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling/

A> I cargo +nighlty create new both ink! smart contracts "other_contract" and "MyContract".
After successful compilation of the "other_contract" when I try to compile "MyContract" it errors saying it cannot find the other_contract module

After doing all the above I also found this post [What is the best way to make a cross contract call on Ink!](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-cross-contract-call-on-ink)  which suggests this is deprecated. Is this correct or there is a way to fix this please?

I am only trying to achieve as per the tutorial example calling one ink! sc method from within another

B> Moved on to https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator

Trying to compile this using $ sh build-all.sh
It errors
ERROR: No 'ink_lang' dependency found

(similar to [Delegator-based contract causes UI interface to crash](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5443/delegator-based-contract-causes-ui-interface-to-crash) )

I have tried replacing
ink = { path = "../../crates/ink", default-features = false }

With

ink_primitives = { version = "3.3", default-features = false }
ink_metadata = { version = "3.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
ink_env = { version = "3.3", default-features = false } 
ink_storage = { version = "3.3", default-features = false } 
ink_lang = { version = "3.3", default-features = false } 
basically following the pattern ink! sc we get with the default contract cargo contract new flipper
But with no success

I would be grateful if anyone has a fix for either of the above solutions?

Comment: what version of rustc are you using? ink 3.3 had an issue where it did not compile with rustc later than 1.64, can you try using ink! 3.4 if you are using newer rustc?

Comment: All works well now
ink! 3.3 
rustc 1.65.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: `cannot find the other_contract module` errors say that you haven't included `other_contract` model in Cargo.toml file. You can take a reference [from this Cargo.toml file](https://github.com/swanky-dapps/marketplace/blob/main/contracts/marketplace/Cargo.toml#L19) in line 19 & 40 for this specific issue and don't forgot to add "rlib" to the crate-type options under "cdylib" in your other_contract/Cargo.toml, "rlib" is used to generate ABI.

B: In order to compile ink! [master branch code example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator), you must have installed [cargo-contract v2.2.0-beta](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#compatibility), then you can compile example code by using `cargo contract build` command.

Comment: Ganesh11 Many thanks for taking the time to respond
A: I have followed the suggestions, triple checked everything but I still have an issue at compiling the MyContract. "endowment is not recognised"
Here is my repo https://github.com/Entity54/ink--cross-contract-calling 
Reminder: I am following tutorial https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling

Comment: @Sokrates I have fixed your code but it didn't allow me to push updated code

Comment: @Sokrates anyway I uploaded the code in my account, [you can get it from here](https://github.com/123oli/ink-cross-contract-calling)

Comment: Many thanks Ganesh11 for your prompt assistance. 
Everything has now compiled and working as expected on a local substrate-contracts-node.
If I may please ask one last thing please. Where can I learn more about the rust syntax  OtherContractRef ,  i.e. what the Ref does instead of using OtherContract. Any good link please on this?

Comment: [have a look here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4779/2844) and [delegator smart contract](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator), may be this could help